# Laravel Migrations Naming Convention

Tags: php, laravel, naming-conventions, database-migration

Is there a naming convention or guide that one should follow while naming Laravel migrations or should the name only be descriptive enough ?

Also, suppose you are adding 12 columns to modify a table then in such a case the migration name would be too long if made descriptive so are there any guide lines to follow ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be descriptive enough for you to check back and understand what did you do with DB in this migration.

If you start migration with table_ then Laravel adds `Schema::create`.
If you have *to* or *from* or *in* then Laravel creates `Schema::table` for you. This makes you life easier.

I usually name the migrations based on feature eg implement_user_roles or make_employee_profile_editable.

Comment: I believe the migrations fail if you don't start them with underscored dates.

Answer (score 19):

According to `\Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\TableGuesser` class source there are two default patterns to guess migration table and stub type.

```
const CREATE_PATTERNS = [
    '/^create_(\w+)_table$/',
    '/^create_(\w+)$/',
];

const CHANGE_PATTERNS = [
    '/_(to|from|in)_(\w+)_table$/',
    '/_(to|from|in)_(\w+)$/',
];
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you don't use the same class name with your model, it still works but for understanding,

Put create_ if you are creating for example,or

If the tables are pivot to each other make it like article_comment to make sure you will understand when you try to change it 5 months later :)